# Where to put *serialization* in SOLID programming

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have business objects, that I would like to (de)serialize from and into a `.yaml` file.

Because I want the `.yaml` to be human readable, I need a certain degree of control over the `serialize` and `deserialize` methods.

Where should the serialization logic go?

A) If I teach every object, how to de/serialize itself, but that probably violates the `single-responsibility-principle`.

B) If I put it inside a common `serialization` module, that might violate the `open-closed-principle`, since more business objects will be added in the future. Also, changes to objects need now be performed in two places.

What is the SOLID approach to solve this conundrum for tiny-scale applications?

Comment: can you explain more about *why* business objects need to be serializable?  Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: @MattTimmermans These business objects are worked on and owned by the users. Every user must be able to **manage** their objects how they want, including downloading or uploading them as yaml files. This allows these objects to be archived, inspected, or shared.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in this kind of situation, you'll want the business objects to handle their own serialization.  This doesn't necessarily violate the single responsibility principle, which asserts that each object should have one job and one boss.  It just means that the one job includes serializability.  The user owns the business object, and wants to be able to serialize it, so the requirement for serializability comes from the same place as those other requirements -- the user.

There are a couple danger areas, though.  Firstly, do *you* really need to insist that the business object is serializable, or can you leave it up to the user to decide whether they are serializable or not?  If you are imposing a serializability requirement, then there's a good chance that your are violating the SRP that way, because as you evolve the serialization system, you will be imposing your own requirements on the objects.

Second, you probably want to think long and hard about the interface the these objects use to serialize themselves.  Does it have to be yaml?  Why?  Does it have to be to a file?  Try not to impose requirements that are subject to change, because they depend on particular implementation decisions that you're making in the rest of the system.  That ends up being a violation of SRP as well, because they those objects have to evolve according to requirements from 2 different sources.  It's better if the objects themselves initiate their own serialization, and can choose the implementation to the greatest extent possible.